# How to get particular word from string in bash

Tags: regex, bash

Example strings:

```
app:mob-type1-subtype:1.0.2
app:mob-type2:1.0.1
```

Above are my example strings, I want to fetch "type" value from above string.

How can I do it using bash script?

I have tried the following

Code:-

```
res="${element#*-}"
echo $res| awk -F : '{ print $1 }'
```

Result (Incorrect one)

```
type1
type2-subtype
```

But I want to get type1 and type2 values only not subtypes. How can I do it in a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cat file

app:mob-type1-subtype:1.0.2
app:mob-type2:1.0.1
```

Using `awk` you can do:

```
awk -F '[:-]' '{print $3}' file
```

```
type1
type2
```

Here is one `bash` solution if you're have input in a shell variable:

```
IFS='[:-]' read -ra arr <<< 'app:mob-type1-subtype:1.0.2'
echo "${arr[2]}"
```

```
type1
```

Comment: What I need to change in code If I want to get "type1-subtype" instead of "type1"

Comment: For that use this `awk -F : '{sub(/[^-]+-/, "", $2); print $2}' file`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, considering your text is in a.txt

```
cat a.txt | grep -Eo "type[0-9]+"
```

It will give the output as below:

type1

type2